# Why is there Generic mismatch for input arguments of two API of collections

Tags: java, generics

I was looking at generic methods of Collections class

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        list.sort(c);
}
```

and other method is

```
 public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        if (c==null)
            return binarySearch((List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>) list, key);

        if (list instanceof RandomAccess || list.size()<BINARYSEARCH_THRESHOLD)
            return Collections.indexedBinarySearch(list, key, c);
        else
            return Collections.iteratorBinarySearch(list, key, c);
    }
```

My question is why sort method is design only for `List<T>` not for `List<? extends T>` as binary search is designed for  `List<? extends T>`?

Answer (score 1):

I am giving the answer to my posted question that I found more accurate.

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        list.sort(c);
}
```

and

```
public static <T> void sort(List<? extends T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        list.sort(c);
}
```

are same. Because we are calling above methods either this way

```
ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Manager(106,true));
list.add(new Manager(102,true));
sort(list, (p1, p2) -> 
p1.getEmployeeId().compareTo(p2.getEmployeeId()));

`T` argument in `sort()` will be considered as Manager in this case
```

or

```
 ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(new Employee(106,true));
 list.add(new Employee(102,true));
 sort(list, (p1, p2) -> 
 p1.getEmployeeId().compareTo(p2.getEmployeeId()));

`T` argument in `sort()` will be Employee in this case.
```

We do not gain anything writing `List<? extends T>` in `sort()`. A real word example if have two balls, then we can use either only one terms, first ball is bigger than second or first ball is smaller than second. Only one thing is possible either bigger or smaller
if we have three balls, we can say, first ball is smaller than second and third ball is bigger than second, then two terms can be used smaller and bigger.

We need some base `T` then we can use either  `? extends T` or  `? super T` or both for example binary search method signature that I have posted above.

JDK also provided sort method with three signature also but in different way

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {
    public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        elementData = c.toArray();
        if ((size = elementData.length) != 0) {
            // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
            if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
                elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
        } else {
            // replace with empty array.
            this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
        }
    }

@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
        final int expectedModCount = modCount;
        Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);
        if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
        modCount++;
    }
```

Above `ArrayList<E>` can be of `E` type, It can accept `Collection<? extends E> c` and can be sorted using `Comparator<? super E> c`. So as per explain we also have three balls

- E type of element It can be
- Collection<? extends E> It can accept list
- Comparator<? super E> c It can be sorted by such comparator

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a list only makes sense only if the list is homogeneous; if one is sorting a pile of papers, it suddenly breaks down if you introduce a whole book in the mix.

Searching a list makes sense if each item is comparable to each other.  If you can define a relationship between a piece of A4 paper and a novel, then you can search between them.

Comment: Thanks Makota..Sorting a list only makes sense only if the list is homogeneous. It is true conceptually but same thing that I asked is provided by JDK in heterogenous manner. I have provided more clear answer in post as well.

Comment: @sdindiver:  Please add your answer as an actual answer, not as a part of your question.

Comment: @Makota Thanks for it. I have posted answer as actual answer

Answer (score 0):

In the sort function, you only have two different types: The type of the list and the type of the comparator. `T` is the type of the elements in the `List`, and `? super T` is the type of the `Comparator`. You do not gain anything by adding
`List<? extends T>` there.

In `binarySearch` you have three types: `T`denotes the type of the `key` to be searched, `? extends T` is the type of the list and `? super T` is the type of the comparator.

Comment: Thanks...Your comment helped to review my question by trying practically with List<T> and List<? extends T>.. I provided clarity of answer that I learnt in post as well.